# Check the comma seperated string against a Enum column in MySQL Where clause

Tags: mysql, enums, where-clause

I'm having a table called `users`, it has a column of datatype enum. I would like to search in `enum` in the `SELECT` query

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` binary(16) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('A','B','C','D','E','F') NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Sample Data:

```
INSERT INTO `cm_contact` (`id`, `name`, `type`)  VALUES
(0x0b0b10bf94e511e9a32efa163e49d265, 'John', 'A,C,E'),
(0x0fd283a494b111e9a32efa163e49d265, 'Ellen', 'E,F'),
(0x25c77b6294e111e9a32efa163e49d265, 'Emma', 'B,C,D');
```

I need to filter the record, that who are all under the type `B` and `C`, that means it will return the user `John` and `Emma`

I tried the following approach but I failed

```
SET @search='B,C';

SELCT * FROM users WHERE type IN @search
```

Kindly assist me how to achieve this.

Comment: Please stop storing delimiter separated values; and instead normalize the DB. Read: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - The FIND_IN_SET() function returns the position of a string within a list of strings. but in my case both are the sets (i.e., list), I need to find any intersection element is there or not.

Comment: ^^ The accepted answer in the duplicate question link shared above is the answer to your problem. But you should really normalize your data, if you really want to fix things structurally and build things for performance.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - Its solved my problem. Thanks.